# Handling null values in dynamic pivot fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'am doing dynamic pivot like these , I wanted to replace Null values in the fields with 0 after pivoting. Not sure how can I achieve that. Here is my query.

```html
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @users TABLE (
 userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
 ,NAME VARCHAR(500)
 );


INSERT INTO @users
SELECT u.id
 ,u.firstname + space(1) + u.lastname NAME
FROM users u
INNER JOIN userparametervalues upv ON u.id = upv.userid
INNER JOIN UserPermissions up ON u.id = up.userid
 AND up.PermissionId IN (
  '34FDF821-E3FF-43B2-AA90-0126BF5FAD56'
  ,'CFC3076F-0BED-4A41-BD1D-0240C4535132'
  )
 AND upv.parameterid = '137696EA-6B68-42E8-A020-2FA5A833F34E'
INNER JOIN users AS u1 ON upv.value = u1.id
 AND u1.UserName IN (
  'IN\libin.jose'
  ,'IN\Pallabi.P'
  )

UNION

SELECT users.id id
 ,users.firstname + space(1) + users.lastname NAME
FROM users
WHERE UserName IN (
  'IN\libin.jose'
  ,'IN\Pallabi.P'
  )


SELECT @cols = STUFF((
   SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(NAME)
   FROM @users
   FOR XML PATH('')
    ,TYPE
   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
SELECT @query = '

SELECT *
FROM
(
  select  LoanPrograms.Name, (case when UserParameterValues.value is null then ''X'' else ''√'' end) as K ,(users.FirstName + space(1)+users.LastName  ) L from LoanPrograms 
 left join UserParameterValues on LoanPrograms.id = UserParameterValues.ValueId and ParameterId = ''CD1DB446-75EF-4887-86ED-4313CCE6D2F1''
  left join users on UserParameterValues.UserId = Users.Id 

) AS t
PIVOT 
(
MAX(k)
  FOR L IN( ' + @cols + ' )' + ' ) AS p ; ';

EXECUTE (@query);
```

I am getting the result like these .

```html
Name                                 Akansha a Lia Jose Libin  Pallabi a
-----------------                       ---------- ---------   -------- ------
CONF 10 YEAR FIXED                    NULL      NULL     NULL Y
CONF 10 YR 105                          NULL     NULL     NULL NULL
CONF 10 YR 125                           NULL     Y         NULL NULL
CONF 10 YR LPMI                          Y        NULL     NULL NULL
CONF 10/1 LIBOR ARM                    NULL     NULL     NULL NULL
```

I wanted to replace all null values by 0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ISNULL` function in the final `SELECT` from the `PIVOT`. For example, you can build the columns list like this:

```
SELECT @SELECTEDcols = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL([' + NAME + '], 0) AS [' + NAME + ']'
            FROM @users
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');
```

and replace the `*` in the final `SELECT` statement with it.

```
SELECT @query = '

SELECT' + @SELECTEDcols + ' 
FROM
(
  select  LoanPrograms.Name, (case when UserParameterValues.value is null then ''X'' else ''√'' end) as K ,(users.FirstName + space(1)+users.LastName  ) L from LoanPrograms 
    left join UserParameterValues on LoanPrograms.id = UserParameterValues.ValueId and ParameterId = ''CD1DB446-75EF-4887-86ED-4313CCE6D2F1''
        left join users on UserParameterValues.UserId = Users.Id    

) AS t
PIVOT 
(
MAX(k)
  FOR L IN( ' + @cols + ' )' + ' ) AS p ; ';
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT @SELECTEDcols = STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL([' + NAME + '], 0) AS [' +NAME + ']'
            FROM @users
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');


SELECT @query = '

SELECT' + @SELECTEDcols + ' 
FROM
(
  select  LoanPrograms.Name, (case when UserParameterValues.value is null then ''X'' else ''√'' end) as K ,(users.FirstName + space(1)+users.LastName  ) L from LoanPrograms 
    left join UserParameterValues on LoanPrograms.id = UserParameterValues.ValueId and ParameterId = ''CD1DB446-75EF-4887-86ED-4313CCE6D2F1''
        left join users on UserParameterValues.UserId = Users.Id    

) AS t
PIVOT 
(
MAX(k)
  FOR L IN( ' + @cols + ' )' + ' ) AS p ; ';
```